# Scope Error when trying to compose Class from another created Class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a simple message passing system in C++ but keep getting thrown errors by the compiler that state 'Topic' is out of scope, even though I have included it.

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H_
#define MESSAGE_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "Topic.h"

namespace EDA {
    class Message {
    private:
        // Message Type
        std::string message_type;

        // List of topics that event is intended for
        const std::vector<Topic> topics;

        // Where all information in the message is
        const std::vector<std::string> payload;

    public:
        Message();
        virtual ~Message();
    };
}
#endif /* MESSAGE_H_ */
```

Here is the exact compiler error printout:

```
20:02:15 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project EDA2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Topic.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Topic.d" -MT"src/Topic.o" -o "src/Topic.o" "../src/Topic.cpp"
In file included from ../src/Topic.h:14,
                 from ../src/Topic.cpp:8:
../src/Message.h:23:21: error: ‘Topic’ was not declared in this scope
   23 |   const std::vector<Topic> topics;
      |                     ^~~~~
../src/Message.h:23:26: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   23 |   const std::vector<Topic> topics;
      |                          ^
../src/Message.h:23:26: error: template argument 2 is invalid
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:29: src/Topic.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

20:02:15 Build Failed. 4 errors, 0 warnings. (took 278ms)
```

And here is the Topic.h file

```
#ifndef TOPIC_H_
#define TOPIC_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "Message.h"
#include "Consumer.h"

namespace EDA {
    class Topic {
    private:
        // Topic Name -- Immutable/Read-only
        const std::string m_TopicName;

        // Subscribers
        std::vector<std::string> m_SubscriberList;

        // Message queue
    public:
        Topic();
        virtual ~Topic();
    };
}
#endif /* TOPIC_H_ */
```

I am new to C++ but want to learn it for scientific & game programming. I have been at this for several days but can't for the life of me understand why it's upset at something that should be in scope. I have even put both classes inside the same namespace but to no avail.

Comment: You have circular includes: `Topic.h` includes `Message.h` which in turn includes `Topic.h`. `Topic.h` doesn't appear to use anything from `Message.h` (or `Consumer.h` for that matter), and so doesn't need to include those headers.

Comment: To fix this bug you need to eliminate the circular header loop.

Comment: In my last run through University, one of my classmates had a Ph/D in genetics. He made a really neat game about viral propagation, thus combining science and gaming.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm actually interested in doing much the same: agent-based simulation coupled with artificial life, possibly with tools for studying them as dynamical systems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Igor Tandetnik. I'm still in the process of trying to put everything together & work things out so I overlooked the fact that both files include each other.

For now I've just merged them and removed the namespace.

```
#pragma once


#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Topic {
private:
    // Topic Name -- Immutable/Read-only
    const std::string m_TopicName;

    // Subscribers
    std::vector<std::string> m_SubscriberList;

    // Message queue
public:
    Topic();
    virtual ~Topic();
};



class Message {
private:
    // Message Type
    std::string message_type;

    // List of topics that event is intended for
    const std::vector<Topic> topics;

    // Where all information in the message is
    const std::vector<std::string> payload;

public:
    Message();
    virtual ~Message();
};
```